# How to automatically update dropdown in a Google Form based on range in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form with a dropdown (see below)
[image]

I have a column on a google sheet that gets updated everyday.

[image]

Is there any way that I can automatically link the names from the google sheet to the google form dropdown Question 1 such that each time the sheet gets updated with an additional name - the google form automatically gets updated with the name in the dropdown. I imagine we would need to use Google AppScript. Any guidance in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very generic script but you should be able to modify it as you see fit

```
function updateForm(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('----------'); // ID of spreadsheet with names
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Names'); // Name of sheet with range of names
  var nameValues = sheet.getRange('A2:A10').getValues(); // Get name values

  var form = FormApp.openById('---------');  // ID of form
  var formItems = form.getItems();
  var question = formItems[2].asListItem(); // Get the second item on the from 

  var names = []

  for(var x = 1; x < nameValues.length; x++){

    if(nameValues[x][0] != ""){ // Ignores blank cells
     names.push(question.createChoice(nameValues[x][0])) // Create an array of choice objects
   } 
  }
  var setQuestion1 = question.setChoices(names); // Update the question

}
```

To update the form when the sheet is edited you can use an installed onEdit trigger. With the addition of logic you can limit the updting of the form to only occour when a particular range has been edited.

In this example the form will only update when an edit has been made to column A of the sheet 'Names'

```
function updateForm(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var getCol = e.range.getColumn(); 

  if(sheetName == 'Names' && 1){

  var nameValues = sheet.getRange('A2:A10').getValues(); // Get name values

  var form = FormApp.openById('---------');  // ID of form
  var formItems = form.getItems();
  var question = formItems[2].asListItem(); // Get the second item on the from 

  var names = []

  for(var x = 1; x < nameValues.length; x++){

    if(nameValues[x][0] != ""){ // Ignores blank cells
     names.push(question.createChoice(nameValues[x][0])) // Create an array of choice objects
   } 
  }
  var setQuestion1 = question.setChoices(names); // Update the question
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am getting this error on running the script ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'asListItem' of undefined (line 9, file "Code")```

Comment: Have you changed the index of the question suit your form? `formItems[2]` since arrays are zero based the first question in the form is [0] if the example in your post is the actual form you are using then change the 2 to 0. You can also use the logger to get the title of the question to confirm `Logger.log(formItems[2].getTitle());`

Comment: Awesome it works. Would you know how I can get this to update automatically such that given any point at which a user is updating the sheet - the form is most up to date? I can think of adding a trigger to the script on sheet edit - do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, an onEdit trigger would be the way to do it. However, you may want to add some logic so the form is only updated when that particular range / column of cells has been changed. See the updated answer.